# Is there an SQL function which generates a given range of sequential numbers?

Tags: sql, informix, auto-increment

I need to generate an array of sequential integers with a given range in order to use it in:

```
SELECT tbl.pk_id
  FROM tbl
 WHERE tbl.pk_id NOT IN (sequential array);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you say you've already got a number table, I would suggest this:

```
SELECT element
FROM series
WHERE element NOT IN (SELECT pk_id
                      FROM tbl)
```

Might possibly be more efficient than the query you've tried.

Comment: definitely simpler and more efficient on the engine!

Answer (score 3):

If you have a given range - ie a start point and an end point - of sequential integers you should just be able to use the `BETWEEN` keyword:

```
SELECT tbl.pk_id
  FROM tbl
 WHERE tbl.pk_id NOT BETWEEN START_INT AND END_INT
```

or am I misunderstanding your question..?

Comment: I dont think BETWEEN would work because some pk_id's are missing since the rows they where in got deleted. Thus, pk_id's 1,2,4,9..would fall BETWEEN 1 AND 5000. pk_id is an INFORMIX SERIAL incrementing INT datatype {autonumber in SQL server}.. When you delete a row having a pk_id, the sequence is broken, so I need a way of finding out which pk_id's are missing.

Comment: @Frank You realize that that's not what you asked for, right?  Your query above gives you "all from table, except X .. Y", and that's what dan_'s solution would do.  Your comment suggests that you need the opposite, you need "all values from X .. Y that do NOT exist in table."

Comment: @Frank Computer: It turns out now that sequential number generator is what you *want*, but what you *need* has happened to be quite a different thing.

Comment: Yes. but I need to know the numbers of the pk_id's that are missing so I created a table called 'series' with one INT column called 'element', populated that table with a series from 1 to 5000, then did a SELECT series.element, tbl.pk_id FROM OUTER tbl, series WHERE series.element = tbl.pk_id; which provides me with NULL values along side the series.element, then I print the series.element which is <= max(tbl.pk_id). It's not the best method, but so far it works!.. but I'm seeking an easier way to achieve my goal.

Comment: @Frank: Have a look at my answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts . . .

First, there's no standard SQL function that does that. But some systems include a non-standard function that does generates a series. In PostgreSQL, for example, you can use the generate_series() function.

```
select generate_series(1,100000);
1
2
3
...
100000
```

That function essentially returns a table; it can be used in joins.

If Informix doesn't have a function that does something similar, maybe you can write an Informix SPL function that does.

Second, you could just create a one-column table and populate it with a series of integers. This works on all platforms, and doesn't require programming. It requires only minimal maintenance. (You need to keep more integers in this table than you're using in your production table.)

```
create table integers (
    i integer primary key
);
```

Use a spreadsheet or a utility program to generate a series of integers to populate it. The easiest way if you have a Unix, Linux, or Cygwin environment laying around is to use `seq`.

```
$ seq 1 5 > integers
$ cat integers
1
2
3
4
5
```

Informix has a [free developer version](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/informix/developer-edition/) you can download. Maybe you can build a compelling demo with it, and management will let you upgrade.

Comment: I previously implemented your second thought and it worked. I created a table called 'series' with one INT column 'element' and loaded it with a 1 to 5000 series. Then I did a SELECT series.element, tbl.pk_id FROM OUTER tbl WHERE series.element = tbl.pk_id; This provided me with a null value for the missing pk_id's along side the series.element, which I then print out series.element to create the list of missing pk_id's. However there should be an easier way of achieving the objective. Keep in mind I'm using Informix's Standard Engine, version 4.10, a real dinasour!

Comment: I don't want to appear insensitive to your problem, but the simplest way to get there from here is to upgrade to an Informix version released sometime in this century. (Wasn't 4.0 released before 1990?) You already knew that, though. Does 4.x support `CREATE VIEW`?

Comment: 4.0 was released 1991. Do you know for a fact that newer version of the SE engine have an SQL auto_generate() function?

Comment: No, I don't know whether the newer versions have a generator function, but I'd expect a more current release to support `CREATE VIEW`, which could be a friendly wrapper for your SELECT statement, and user-defined functions.

Comment: CREATE VIEW has been around since the first release of ISQL. But why would I want to use it if Andriy M's suggestion is good?.. I will populate a series table with sequential numbers high enough to use it for multiple purposes in the future.

Comment: A view can wrap any SELECT statement, possibly making it simpler to use. If your version supports `LEFT JOIN`, this might dramatically outperform `NOT IN` on large tables: `SELECT element FROM series LEFT JOIN tbl on (pk_id = element ) WHERE pk_id IS NULL`. Wrap that in a view named 'missing_pk_ids' and relax on the beach.

Answer (score 0):

i'll suggest a generic solution to create a result set containing the positive integers 0 .. 2^k-1 for a given k for subsequent use as a subquery, view or materialized view.
the code below illustrates the technique for k=2.

```
SELECT bv0 + 2* bv1 + 4*bv2   val
  FROM (
        SELECT *
          FROM 
                             (
                                SELECT 0 bv0 FROM DUAL
                                 UNION
                                SELECT 1 bv0 FROM DUAL
                             ) bit0
                 CROSS JOIN  (
                                SELECT 0 bv1 FROM DUAL
                                 UNION
                                SELECT 1 bv1 FROM DUAL
                             ) bit1
                 CROSS JOIN  (
                                SELECT 0 bv2 FROM DUAL
                                 UNION
                                SELECT 1 bv2 FROM DUAL
                             ) bit2
      ) pow2
;
```

i hope that helps you with your task

best regards,

carsten

Comment: As written, doesn't that rely on Oracle features?

Comment: the dummy table 'dual' is specific to oracle. you can use  'SELECT 0/1 FROM "informix".SysTables WHERE TabID = 1;' for informix or 'SELECT 42 FROM SysTables WHERE TabID = 1;' for other rdbms. note: i haven't tested this but taken the example from http://search.cpan.org/~timb/dbd-summaries/dbd-informix.pod

Comment: the more general approach is to take a result set of cardinality 1 of your choice and select 0/1 from it.

Comment: I'm using an old version of Informix's standard engine (4.10) so DUAL is not supported. However, I can easily get around that. I created a table called 'dummy' with one INT column = 1 and one row. So if I do a SELECT * FROM dummy, the result is one row containing a 1. Will this workaround work with your above example?

Comment: does your db engine support select-ing constant values like 'select 0 as bv0 from dummy' and 'select 1 as bv0 from dummy' ? if it does, use dummy instead of dual in the query above. otherwise you need 2 single-row-tables dummy0 and dummy1 with a int column=0 and int column=1, resp. - use 'select * bv0 from dummy0 union select * from dummy1' instead of the queries from dual. remember to use different column aliases (bv0, bv1, ...) for each of the join components.

Comment: yes, SE 4.10 supports SQL constant values, but I'm going to stick with my series table method mentioned in Andriy M's answer. It's simpler and more efficient. Having a series table for lookups can come in handy for other things.